# php/mysql proper way to query timezone sensitive rows

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm storing rows users in my database as rows. I'm allowing the users to input their timezone, which gets stored in the db as well.

My app will email them every day at a time they specify. I store the email delivery as a row in another db table. This will happen via a cron job.

I'd like my query to pull user records where the latest email for that user was at least 1400 minutes(24 hrs ago) and passed their specified time, according to their timezone.

I have the following query, but i don't know how to account for mysql's timezone and the user's timezone. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.timezone_offset, u.email_time, TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
MINUTE , CONCAT( DATE( MAX( e.created ) ) ,  ' ', u.email_time ) , NOW( ) ) AS min_since_last_email
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Emails e ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE min_since_last_email > 1400
GROUP BY u.id
```

the timezone offset is the offset from GMT..so it would be something like "-5" for me.

Comment: I would probably suggest getting rid of the `min_since_last_email` and just leave it as a time zone offset. Then just query all the ones that need to be sent at that time. So for example, assuming it goes out at 2pm for everyone. So at 4pm GMT (2pm + 2 hours) query `WHERE tz = -2` and send the email only to those users.

Comment: well i want to eventually allow them to specify the interval every day, every two days, every three days, etc.

Comment: In that case you could also have `last_email_sent` as `DATE` and `email_every` as `INT` and do `WHERE tz = -1 * timezone_offset AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), last_email_sent) >= email_every`. I THINK that should work. I really don't like working with `INT`s for dates/times.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the logic around a bit: do the calculations in PHP, store everything in the database in UTC. Then it's a simple extract. You can do this in PHP using the timezone functions easily enough and that can be customised per user - the SQL statement is a global statement that is trickier to customise per user (as you're experiencing).

So the "time e-mail is to be sent" may be 4am UTC (and that's in the database) but you display to the user "9pm".

One problem you may have is Daylight Savings - when the timezone flips in to/out of Daylight Savings you'll need to recalculate all the times. However you're current method doesn't allow for this anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The date you last sent the email is *your* date, so store that.

As you send more and more email, computing the max per user will get more and more expensive.  Denormalize and put a copy of that datetime in the user record as well.

Then, compute the age of that date and offset for the user's timezone.

```
select *, date_add(now(), interval timezone_offset hour) as email_expected_on
from users
where last_email_date <= date_add(now(), interval timezone_offset hour);
```

Note that it's also important that you not apply a formula to users.last_email_date, or you won't be able to use an index on that column.